# Using a dictionary (with changing values) as a flyweight in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

Suppose I create a dictionary

`d = {i:False for i in range(0,100)}`

Then I make a list

`l = [d[12], d[10], d[70]]`

and then change the dictionary:

`d[12] = True...`

the list doesn't change, is this behavior expected? If so, how can I add the values as references?

I'm doing this in a more complicated context, but this is the first thing I wanted to investigate (of many potential issues, I just wrote this).

Here's the full code:

```
import csv

# create a bingo num flyweight --> we don't have to update every board
b = {i:False for i in range(0,100)}

boards = []
with open("04.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # get the numbers to be drawn
    draw = list(map(int, next(reader)))
    # skip the first emptyline before boards start
    next(reader)
    # we want to store each board as a list of rows and columns
    #   i.e. 5x5 board is a 5x10 list, this will make checking easier
    board = []
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        if len(row) < 1:
            boards.append(board[:] + list(map(list, list(zip(*board)))))
            board = []
        else:
            board.append([b[int(i)] for i in filter(None,row[0].split(" "))])
    
for i in range(0, 100):
    b[i] = True

print(boards[0])
```

I suspect the way that I append `board` to `boards` could be the culprit...

You might recognize this as an 'advent of code' problem, I promise I can solve it with a more rudimentary technique, I just don't want to give up on this method... thank you!

Comment: Technically, both list and dict start out with references to the same value. But then you replace the reference when you intended to *midify* the reference's target instead - which you cannot do in this case, because bools are immutable.

Comment: You can achieve "mutable bools" by wrapping them in a mutable container. The simplest is `i: [False]` instead of `i:False`. You can also exploit that empty lists are false'y for the specific problem of "mutable bools".